# how to extended template call the other template in jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm calling a template in extended template.

I can't not find 'how to extended template call the other template in jinja2?'

base.html

```html
<div class="main-container">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

child.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="child">
  <button class="modal"/>
  {% modal content %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

modal content.html

```html
<div class="modal-content">
...some code
</div>
```

I want call modal content in child.html.

Comment: Call JS code in content.html?

Comment: Yes! I'm moved javascript in context.html into child.html and child.html use {% include %} keyword extend content.html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're meaning you want to add the content.html into the child.html page, use [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#include)

Within child.html:

`{% include 'content.html' %}`